# Automapper throws exception on mapping object with hidden properties with different types

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, automapper

Here are my classes:

```
public class A
{
public int archive {get; set;}
}

public class B : A
{
 public new bool archive {get; set;}
}

public class aDTO
{
public int archive {get; set;}
}

public class bDTO : aDTO
{
 public new bool archive {get; set;}
}
```

Now, when I try to use AutoMapper to map class bDTO to class B it throws an exception. Here is my mapper code I am using.

```
IEnumerable<bDTO> myBDTOCollection = getCollection;
Mapper.CreateMap<bDTO, B>();
IEnumerable<B> BList = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<bDTO>, IEnumerable<B>>(myBDTOCollection);
```

I dont know if I am missing something simple or if there is a better way to do this or what. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: Trying to map DTO.bDTO to DomainLogic.B.
Using mapping configuration for DTO.bDTO to DomainLogic.B
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much deliberation and battling with AutoMapper I discovered the source of almost every issue I have run into so far.

Once your objects start to gain in complexity it becomes prudent that when mapping them you dont use the interface for the source and/or destination.

In some cases (like with my DTO's) I was still able to use the Interface, but for the business logic objects AutoMapper prefered the concrete type to be used.

In reality, when I was creating maps, I was mapping the interfaces for my objects:
**Mapper.CreateMap<IbDTO, IB>()**

What fixed my issue is when I mapped the concrete type for the business object:
**Mapper.CreateMap<IbDTO, B>()**

This fixed my problem and every other problem I have been having with Auto Mapper so far.

Answer (score 0):

For starters that code wont compile ...

```
public new archive bool {get; set;}
```

should be ...

```
public new bool archive {get; set;}
```

Your problem is you have the type arguments for CreateMap the wrong way around ... order is 
`Mapper.CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()`

This should work ...

```
Mapper.CreateMap<bDTO, B>();
IEnumerable<B> BList = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<bDTO>, IEnumerable<B>>(myBDTOCollection);
```

As a suggestion I think the syntax mapping whole collections is messy ... I prefer this ...

```
IEnumerable<B> BList = myBDTOCollection.ToList().ConvertAll(Mapper.Map<bDTO, B>);
```

Either way will do the trick tho ... just a preference :)

Comment: I had some typos from hand jamming the example code. I went ahead and fixed them. I tried the mappings both ways as you suggested but it fails. I really believe that it has something to do with the property hiding through inheritance using the "new" keyword that automapper doesnt like.

Comment: I don't think thats the case ... I ran the code exactly as it appears above and it worked fine? Unfortunately automapper throws really crap exceptions that don't really tell you anything about what's going wrong so errors are often hard to find. If you think its the hiding then make the property in A virtual and use the override keyword in B ... but I doubt that will make any difference to be honest.